# Match an array of foreign keys in one table with primary key in another table?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I have a two tables. One like this:

```
id   | array_of_ids
----------------------
 001 | {012, 345, 789}
 002 | {789, 123, 456}
 003 | {234, 789, 567}
 004 | {543, 210, 789}
```

Another like this:

```
 ids  | str
-------------
 012 | am_name1
 345 | name2
 789 | name3
 123 | am_name4
 456 | name5
 234 | name6
 567 | am_name7
 543 | am_name8
 210 | name9
```

I want to create a table that looks like this:

```
id   | array_of_ids    | label
-----------------------------
 001 | {012, 345, 789} | name1
 002 | {789, 123, 456} | name4
 003 | {234, 789, 567} | name7
 004 | {543, 210, 789} | name8
```

I know that which label gets populated looks random, but here's some more details: every id has a corresponding name, but i am only interested in certain type of name -- the one's with the prefix 'am'. I want to be able to scan the `array_of_ids`, check if a id in the array matches a `str` i am interested in and the populate a new variable `label` with the correspond name. I hope this is clear! Happy to edit if necessary!

Comment: When was the time that database designers thought it important to *normalise* their model? I am of the old school. I don't understand this need to store arrays with primary keys in *one* field. Normalisation rule number 1 is?

Comment: hi @trincot, i didnt design the tables! the arrays aren't of primary keys. the arrays are of foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, well the point is that putting multiple reference data in one field is plain bad design. It's less bad for text, and other information that just provides details about the core data, but even that would be against the normal forms.

Comment: yes @trincot, i agree!

Answer (score 1):

[`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) and `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.array_of_ids,
       max(case when regexp_like(t2.name, '^am_') then substr(t2.name, 4) end)
from table1 t1 cross join
     unnest(t1.array_of_ids) t1_id(id) join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1_id.id
group by t1.id, t1.array_of_ids;
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and will report back!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I wasn't making use of the PRESTO's [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html). This solution is a little clunky since it requires you to look up each id/name pair outside of the solution, but it works.

```
SELECT id, array_of_ids,
  CASE WHEN CONTAINS(array_of_ids, 012) = TRUE THEN 'name1'
       WHEN CONTAINS(array_of_ids, 123) = TRUE THEN 'name4'
       WHEN CONTAINS(array_of_ids, 567) = TRUE THEN 'name7'
       WHEN CONTAINS(array_of_ids, 543) = TRUE THEN 'name8'
       ELSE NULL END AS label
FROM table1
```